# SSRS -> Chart showing more labels on the horizontal axis than present within the data provided to the chart?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a chart that I provide 16 records to.  Currently, the x axis is datetime and the y axis is a numeric value that is plotted on a line chart.  I set the interval to 1 so that it shows all the labels for the horizontal axis, but now it is showing 1 extra label on the far left and 1 extra label on the far right of the horizontal axis.  The odd part is there is no data so the chart starts not on the edge but 1 label in and ends one label in on the right.

Just wondering if someone has seen this before I am using visual studio 2008.

I have created these charts before just never seen this issue before.

Exmaple pic. :
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting was within the properties of the horizontal axis.  Set margin property equal to false.